# mmenu doesn't work anymore after cloning the menu

Tags: mmenu

I used http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ and it worked fine for me when I didn't clone the navigation.
But, if I use to clone the menu, the menu doesn't open anymore.

Any solutions why this happened?

Comment: Test case with code or it didn't happen.

Comment: You need to post your code to get an accurate reply. Anyway, I bet that you used an id to indicate what turns into a menu. When you clone it, you have the same id twice, which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out why this happened.
After cloning the id is prefixed with mm- idName. The anchor to open the navigation has also to be prefixed but it wasn't. I changed it to also to #mm-main-navigation and everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this issue has been fixed in version 3.0.4